# How can I fill multiple docx files with data from one xml file using docx4j?

Tags: java, xml, ms-word, docx4j

I'm trying to fill data from one xml file to a docx template that would generate multiple word files

```
public static final String input_DOCX = "E:\\Temp5\\Word document template.docx";

public static final String input_XML = "E:\\Temp5\\Word document data.xml";

public static final String output_DOCX = "E:\\Temp5\\Word document output.docx";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));
    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input_XML));
    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(output_DOCX), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    System.out.println("Saved: " + output_DOCX);
```

I want something that would be similar to this code but for multiple docx files. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just iterate over the docx files, or do I misunderstand what you are asking?

Comment: @JasonPlutext Sorry about that, it's supposed to be like a report where it would output a Word file for each person. The XML file would have Information about multiple people. For example, my XML file would have information about Jack, Peter, and Lindsey in it and this code would fill a template to create 3 separate Word files with their information on the output. Hopefully, I didn't make it more confusing.

Comment: In that case, you'll need to preprocess your XML file.  That is extract the info for Jack (creating Jack.xml input stream or whatever) then run the binding process to create your first docx.  Then extract the info for Peter, and so on.